# ¿Por qué obtengo valores negativos en una diferencia de tiempos tomados con System.currentTimeMillis()?

Tags: java

Contexto: Estoy graficando los tiempos que tardan en completarse varios algoritmos de ordenamiento para distintas entradas (N).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me extraña es que hay un pico negativo, en la imagen es sobre la curva de color amarillo que pertenece al comportamiento del burbuja optimizado.

La manera en que obtengo el tiempo total de completitud del algoritmo es la siguiente:

```
    public void sort(double[] data) {
        this.initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Código del algoritmo...
        this.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.totalTime = this.endTime - this.initTime;
    }
```

El tipo de dato de initTime, endTime y totalTime es long, y se inicializan con 0 en el constructor.

Nota: Nunca antes me había pasado.

Comment: probaste con el debug ver el valor de initTime, por que alomejor en algun momento toma unvalor mucho mayor a endTime y por eso te da negativo

Comment: ¿Cómo generas las gráficas? El código que muestras no lo deja claro, y puede ser un error de pasos posteriores (al guardar un log, por ejemplo). ¿Cuál es el dato más básico que te muestra un valor negativo?

Comment: Podria ser un problema de concurrencias. A esa función le llamas desde diferentes Threads?